# Angular JS "ng-repeat" is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

here is my code:
In this code my ng-repeat is not working

```
    <br/>
        <h3>Looping with ng-repeat directive</h3>   
            <ul>
                <li data-ng-repeat="name in names init">{{names}}</li>

            </ul>

    </div>      
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please post a Json representation of 'names'? Also, I think you should put {{name}} instead of {{names}}.

Comment: What's that ```init``` doing there in the ng-repeat?

Answer (score 2):

ng-repeat works like a for loop (if you're familiar with Java, it works exactly like a for-each loop).
The syntax is

```
ng-repeat="item in listOfItems"
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

What happens here is that the repeater will generate the content annotated with the ng-repeat for as many items the list contains (see the example [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#example)).

In your case, as Vamsi V said, you'd need something like

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names">{{ name }}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

If names is an array of names like

```
$scope.names = ['John', 'Jack', 'Joe'];
```

you have to use

```
<li ng-repeat="name in names">{{ name }}</li>
```

If persons is an array of objects like

```
$scope.persons = [{name: 'John', age: 20}, {name: 'Jack': age: 21}];
```

you have to use

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{ person.name }}</li>
```